# Running different tasks simultaneously in python?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, python-3.5

I've written a python program to continuously do the following on a Raspberry Pi 3B+:

- Check date/time.
- Check if a directory is available with the current date/time as name, if not make a directory.
- Read serial data from a sensor.
- Convert serial data to readable results.
- Check results for triggers.
- Check GPIO pins for an extra, external trigger.
- IF triggered: take a picture using a PiCamera module, save the picture with date/time as name in the directory, create/append results in a .txt file.

The program mostly does what I intended it to do, but when I check the results in the .txt file, some results are 'impossible' and indicate I'm not reading/converting my serial data properly. The sensor also outputs data at 100 telegrams/second, which is nowhere near the actual rate at which the Raspberry Pi is saving results (around 2 measurements/second).

I've tried writing a program that only reads the serial data, nothing else, and this is able to keep up with the sensor. I also tried replacing the checking of the header with a ser.read_until() (leaving the useless headers at the end of each telegram). However this resulted in telegrams of varying lengths, making the parsing into the 6 variables harder. [Check this link to see what a telegram consists of according to specs.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDj6X.png)
The code I use now (below) reads the telegram in pieces (2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1 bytes) but sometimes returns values that seem misinterpreted.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import time, serial, os, sys, stat, os.path, subprocess                                 
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from picamera import PiCamera
from datetime import datetime

ser = serial.Serial(                                                                    
    port='/dev/serial0',
    baudrate = 19200,
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
    timeout=0)

signaltrigger = 60
trigger = 24
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)                                                                  
GPIO.setup(trigger, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)                                

now = datetime.now()                                                                    
data_dir = now.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
save_path = "/home/pi/serial/"+data_dir+"/"                                            
test = os.path.isdir(save_path)                                                         
if test == False:                                                                       
    os.mkdir(save_path)                                                                 
    subprocess.call(['chmod', '-R', '777', '/home/pi/serial'])                          
else:
    pass

cam = PiCamera()                                                                        
cam.rotation = 90                                                                       
cam.resolution = (480, 360)                                                             
cam.start_preview()                                                                     
signaltriggerA = 0
signaltriggerB = 0

while 1:
    now = datetime.now()                                                                    
    time_exact = now.strftime(str(now)[11:23])                                          
    date_time = now.strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M")                                          
    data_dir = now.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")                                                 
    save_path = "/home/pi/serial/"+data_dir+"/"                                         
    completename = os.path.join(save_path, date_time+".txt")                            
    namepic = str(time_exact+".jpg")
    completenamepic = os.path.join(save_path, data_dir+" "+time_exact+".jpg")           
    test = os.path.isdir(save_path)                                                     
    if test == False:                                                                   
        os.mkdir(save_path)                                                             
        subprocess.call(['chmod', '-R', '777', '/home/pi/serial'])
        pass
    else:
        pass
    x = ser.read(3)                                                                     
    if x != b'~~~':                                                                     
        print("Header mismatched")
        x = ser.read(9)                                                                 
        d = 0
        j = 0
    elif x == b'~~~':
        print("Serial communication started...")
        y = ser.read(2)                                                                 
        a = ser.read(2)
        c = ser.read(1)
        e = ser.read(2)
        g = ser.read(2)
        i = ser.read(1)
        z = int.from_bytes(y, byteorder='little', signed=False)/100                     
        b = round(int.from_bytes(a, byteorder='little', signed=True)*0.0367, 2)
        d = int.from_bytes(c, byteorder='little', signed=False)                         
        f = int.from_bytes(e, byteorder='little', signed=False)/100                     
        h = round(int.from_bytes(g, byteorder='little', signed=True)*0.0367, 2)
        j = int.from_bytes(i, byteorder='little', signed=False)                         
    if d >= signaltrigger:
        signaltriggerA = 1
    else:
        signaltriggerA = 0
    if j >= signaltrigger:
        signaltriggerB = 1
    else:
        signaltriggerB = 0
    if signaltriggerA or signaltriggerB or GPIO.input(trigger):        
        cam.capture(completenamepic)
        M = open(completename,"a+",encoding='utf-8')                                    
        M.write('[%s]: Distance(a) = %s [m], Velocity(a) = %s [km/h], Signal(a) = %s [dB], Distance(r) = %s [m], Velocity(r) = %s [km/h], Signal(r) = %s [dB]. Trigger(a) = %s, Trigger(r) = %s, Trigger(ETZ) = %s. Picture: %s\n'%(time_exact,z,b,d,f,h,j,signaltriggerA,signaltriggerB,GPIO.input(trigger),namepic))
        M.close()
        pass
    else:
        print("No triggers detected")
```

I expect the program to parse each incoming telegram into 6 pieces and translate these pieces into results (integers or floats), but sometimes the values of these results turn out way too high (impossible for the sensor). I expect this to be caused by manually reading the different bytes (taking too much time and missing parts of the telegram as the sensor continuously spits out data). 
How could I ensure the correct reading and converting of the serial data? Also if the sensor outputs data at 100 telegrams/second but the camera can't keep up with 100 pictures/second, is it possible to calculate a moving average instead of using just one of many telegrams?
Edit: Added picture of telegram's specifications to help understand the serial data + added complete python program.

Comment: What's a *"telegram"* please? Why have you removed all the `import` statements? What is the sensor you are reading from?

Comment: If you test `if x != b'~~~'` it is not necessary to test the converse in your `else` statement.

Comment: If you are out of sync with the three byte header of `"~~~"`, I wonder if it might be better to read single extra characters to try and get back in sync rather than keeping on reading 9 bytes when you are clearly no longer aligned on a 9-byte boundary. I am not sure on this... just thinking aloud.

Comment: Near your `pass` statements, you might do better with `if not os.path.isdir(save_path):` then `os.mkdir(save_path)` and just omit the `else` clause.

Comment: Maybe you could use a subprocess or different thread to capture the picture so you can keep up with the incoming serial data in the main thread?

Comment: Rather than calling `ser.read()` 6 times to get 10 bytes, maybe you could call it once and read all 10 bytes in one go, then just use indices in `int.from_bytes()` to access specific offsets? `buffer=ser.read(10)` then `y=int.from_bytes(buffer[:2]...`

Comment: @MarkSetchell By telegram I mean the serial data of one measurement (the '~~~' header and then 10 bytes of data). Also because I expect 10 bytes of actual data, I thought reading 9 and then checking again for headers would mean I'm checking a new position. This way I'd get an alignment-error for 9 times max, and then the telegrams should be synchronized with the python program, right? 
Also I've been trying to figure out if threading/multiprocessing could be a solution, but this honestly is my first python program ever and I'd have no idea how to start and which alternative to take.

Comment: `os.mkdir()` can take the mode as argument, there is no need to call the external `chmod`, and with `os.makedirs()` you can even skip the test if the path already exists if you pass the `exist_ok` argument. All those one character variable names are seriously messed up!

Comment: @BlackJack I ran into a problem before where I couldn't open/remove pictures made by the camera because of incorrect permissions. Using `chmod` allowed me to make sure everything in the directory was available for any kind of editing, but calling this every time for every file must make the program a lot slower too unfortunately. Can I use an argument to fix the permissions during the writing of images/files so I won't need `chmod` anymore?

Answer (score 0):

I would use `read_until()` to read up to the three header bytes and some saner and more readable way to turn the data bytes into values.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from ctypes import LittleEndianStructure, c_int16, c_uint16, c_uint8, sizeof
from datetime import datetime
import os


class SensorData(LittleEndianStructure):
    _pack_ = 1
    _fields_ = [
        ('_distance', c_uint16),
        ('_velocity', c_int16),
        ('signal_strength', c_uint8),
    ]

    @property
    def distance(self):
        return self._distance / 100

    @property
    def velocity(self):
        return self._velocity * 0.0367

    def to_string(self, name):
        return (
            f'Distance({name}) = {self.distance} [m],'
            f' Velocity({name}) = {self.velocity} [km/h],'
            f' Signal({name}) = {self.signal_strength} [dB]'
        )


class Message(LittleEndianStructure):
    _pack_ = 1
    _fields_ = [
        ('sensor_a', SensorData),
        ('sensor_b', SensorData),
    ]


def main():
    # ...

    while True:
        now = datetime.now()
        save_path = f'/home/pi/serial/{now:%d-%m-%Y}'
        log_path = os.path.join(save_path, f'{now:%d-%m-%Y %H:%M}.txt')
        picture_filename = f'{now:%H:%M:%S.%f}.jpg'
        picture_path = os.path.join(save_path, picture_filename)
        os.makedirs(save_path, exist_ok=True)

        ser.read_until(b'~~~')
        message = Message.from_buffer_copy(ser.read(sizeof(Message)))
        signal_trigger_a = message.sensor_a.signal_strength >= signal_trigger
        signal_trigger_b = message.sensor_b.signal_strength >= signal_trigger
        gpio_trigger = GPIO.input(trigger)
        if signal_trigger_a or signal_trigger_b or gpio_trigger:
            cam.capture(picture_path)
            with open(log_path, 'a', encoding='utf-8') as log_file:
                log_file.write(
                    f'[{now}]:'
                    f' {message.sensor_a.to_string("a")},'
                    f' {message.sensor_a.to_string("r")}.'
                    f' Trigger(a) = {signal_trigger_a},'
                    f' Trigger(r) = {signal_trigger_b},'
                    f' Trigger(ETZ) = {gpio_trigger}.'
                    f' Picture: {picture_filename}\n'
                )
        else:
            print('No triggers detected')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: After some hassle to get python 3.6+ (3.7.3 now) in order to make these `f' ` statements work, I can say the program outputs data when expected, just not the data that was expected. For example the signal strength should be somewhere between 30 and 50 dB but I'm reading values anywhere from 0 to 255. This makes me think I might still read a wrong byte or combination of bytes before translating to integers. With `readuntil()` I can guarantee my variable ends with the header of a telegram, but how could I make sure I get the right bytes? Using `time.sleep(x)` or `ser.flushInput()` hasn't worked.